# Flutter, return 2 widgets from class or method

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this hacky/ugly way of return 2 widgets from a function and adding them to a children[...]

The widget being created

```
List<Widget> _buildTextData() {
  final Text headingText = Text(
    heading,
    style: MyFontStyle.sizeXs,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  );
  final Text subheadingText = Text(
    subheading,
    style: MyFontStyle.make(fontSize: FontSizes.Xxs, color: MyColor.grey),
  );

  ....code

  return [headingText, subheadingText];
}
```

The widgets being added

```
    children: [
       ...other_widgets
    ]..addAll(_buildTextData())
```

Is there a nicer way to do this without having to call the function inside the `..addAll()`??

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your function and the way you are adding items to the list. As a general rule, always keep functions as small as possible (e.g. separate functions for heading and subheading, if possible)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `sync*` function combined with `yield*` operator to create such list.

```
List<Widget> otherWidgets;

List<Widget> children = () sync* {
  yield Text("Foo");
  yield* otherWidgets;
}().toList();
```